What kind of connector is this white, 4 in-line, 0.1" pitch?
I found this connector inside my acoustic guitar preamp. (It's an Equis II preamp from the '90s.)
Now the cables are sometimes failing and I'd like to replace the whole connector+cables or at least find a way to replace the cables
It is 1 cm wide.
I did a reverse image search on Google but I did not find the exact type.


It is probably compatible with a Molex CONN RCPT HSG 4POS 2.54MM which has the contacts as a 2.54 mm spacing:



I say probably since there is only the width mentioned in the question.
The datasheet linked from the above DigiKey page shows that the version with 4 contacts has DIM. B as 10.72 mm, which ties in with the "It is 1cm wide" from the question:




FWIW, I see these every day and there's no "probably" about it. It's a 4 pin KK254. Each wire gets stripped 2mm and crimped to a contact. The hard part is finding a crimp tool to do it right.

thank you very much. I'm pretty sure this is my connector. After work I'm going to measure it precisely so I can accept your answer

@MattS no problem finding the correct crimp tool - the issue is that it very expensive. Finding a crimp tool at a hobbyist friendly price that does a good job is the tricky part. The Japanese brand ‘Engineer’ have some reasonable tools I’m told.
